# Action method is not called from $.ajax POST whenever the sent text contains "<"

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc, html-escape-characters

I'm using the following to display some text on my intranet site:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Text)
```

Now the text may contain some XML-like formatting, which seems to present a problem when I try the following on form submit:

```
$("form").on("submit", function () {
  var model = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Test/Foo",
    type: "POST",
    data: model,
    dataType: "json",
    success: doSomething(response)
  });
  return false;
});
```

The action method takes a POCO which serves as the model of the site with the form I'm submitting and returns some `JsonResult`.

As long as the text in the `<textarea>` is "normal" text, there is no problem and I enter the action method correctly and my POCO has the correct property values. But once I enter the text `<foo>` (with the braces) into the `<textarea>`, my action method isn't hit anymore.

I tried using `$(this).serializeArray()` instead and it doesn't work either. The `serialize()` and `serializeArray()` methods even replace the "<" and ">" signs (and also "="; first I thought that this was causing the problem), so I guess they're internally using `escape()`, but nothing is sent.

When I manually send as `data`

```
{
  Text: escape($("#myTextArea").val()),
  Description: $("#someInput").val(),
  Id: $("input[type=hidden]").val()
}
```

it works, that is, I enter my action method, but of course I have a weirdly formatted string to work with on the server.

What exactly is the problem here? Some encoding issue? Do I have to serialize in some other way to circumvent this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a security feature of ASP.Net MVC. By default when it detects HTML in a received value it will prevent execution in case it is part of an XSS attack.

To disable this feature on an Action you need to use the `ValidateInput` attribute and set it to `false`. Try this:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Foo(Model myModel) 
{
    // your logic here...
}
```

You can also disable this on a model property level by using the `AllowHtml` attribute:

```
public class MyModel {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    public String Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! `[ValidateInput(false)]` works well, but does that disable all validation even on the site? I'd rather have liked to use `[AllowHtml]` but that doesn't work for me. Is there any other prerequisite I need for that to work? The class I use is the model of the partial view that contains the form I'm serializing,

Comment: Nevermind, I was stupid. My model also contains a property `Description`, but also a property `Text` which is the one I want to allow HTML input to, but after reading your example I added the attribute to `Description` ;)